# I have some questions

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, paint-3d

1 - What is the difference between the following 3D programs and what is appropriate for work in terms of simplicity and professional capabilities

Houdini FX

Autodesk Maya

ZBrush

Blender

2 - Do 3D designs enter into the games movements

I know many questions, but please help as you can

Comment: Sorry but your question is quite broad to be answered as it is. "The best" will depend on each ones' personal preference, and even "appropriate" will depend on the project. The site has a Q&A format instead of a discussion forum. Check [ask] and take the [tour], then [edit] your question to make it more focused and more clear.

Comment: The second question is not clear at all. What is a game movement?

Answer (score 1):

This question will be closed because it is too broad, but I will give you some tips.

There are different modeling techniques and different purposes for a program. For the ones you mention.

- Zbrush is for sculpting, the metaphor is clay sculpting.
- Houdini is known for the procedural approach, natural shapes like rocks, natural phenomena like fire effects.
- Maya for animation, especially characters.
- Blender for getting a bit of everything.

> professional capabilities

This is not about one is pro and other is noob, the user is, the program not.

---

But stop wasting time asking general questions, look at the gallery of each, and download some of them.

Houdini has a free apprentice version, Maya has a student version free for some years, and Blender is free for life.

Read the hardware specs, because are quite humungous.